# Container view transitions between UITableViewController and UIViewController, why are the bounds messed up?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to implement a flip between two view controllers embedded into a container view. In the real app, the flip button swaps between a map and a list.

In this mockup of the problem, the Coffee UITableViewController is swapped out for the Sweets UIViewController.

[image: layout in IB]

It works fine in the simple case, but when I add a segue to the Sweets Controller to go to a child UIViewController, things go awry after the following actions - Flip - segue - Back - Flip. Repeat those actions and the tableview slowly makes its way down off the screen.

[image: space appears between nav bar and tableview]

The code in FlipViewController is:

```
@interface FlipViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *controller1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *controller2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *currentViewController;
@end

@implementation FlipViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.controller1 = [self.childViewControllers firstObject];
    self.currentViewController = self.controller1;

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    self.controller2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Sweets Controller"];
    [self addChildViewController:self.controller2];
}


- (IBAction)flip:(id)sender {
    if (self.currentViewController == self.controller1) {
        [self transitionFromViewController:self.controller1 toViewController:self.controller2 duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.controller2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            self.currentViewController = self.controller2;
        }];
    }
    else {
        [self transitionFromViewController:self.controller2 toViewController:self.controller1 duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.controller2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            self.currentViewController = self.controller1;
        }];
    }
}
@end
```

Some debugging seems to indicate the bounds of the UITableView is getting confused upon return. Do I have an AutoLayout problem or is my approach with transitionFromViewController: the wrong way to go about getting this effect? Any suggestions would be appreciated, I've been stuck on this bug for too long!?

Comment: Is it a `UITableView` on a regular `UIViewController` or a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: In this mockup its a UITableViewController, but I've tried with a UIViewController containing a UITableView and I still get the problem.

Comment: Is the position changing by 20 every time?

Comment: Oh right.  I'm not sure of the exact cause or solution, but... 64 = 20 (status bar) + 44 (navigation bar).